# Infinite loop with Safari using Adal JS and ADFS 4.0

Tags: adfs, adal.js

I experience problems with Safari when running Adal JS 1.0.13 together with a local ADFS 4.0.

**Safari:** after a successful redirect back from the ADFS login screen the browser goes into an infinite loop. The sessionStorage is updated approximately 3 times/second with new values each time. If I reload the page later the same loop starts. To reach the login screen I must select “Remove all Website data”. Cookie settings: always accept.

**Firefox / Chrome:** login works fine and the application runs perfectly. Three cookies are available MSISAuth, MSISAuthenticated & MSISLoopDetectionCookie.

“Keep me signed in” is not selected by the user and the parameter “cacheLocation” is not specified (i.e. use sessionStorage).

Any ideas what causes Safari to behave in this way?

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons this could be happening and you will need to specifically follow up with adal.js team. See this [FAQ](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/FAQs) from adal.js team.

I recommend collecting adal logs and attaching it to the github issue.

Irrespective of the root cause, the adal.js team recommends two solutions

1. Specify a different html for the iframe - [Gist](https://gist.github.com/tushargupta51/5fa6d000357120adbc8fd1d5c68853c4)
2. Conditional initialization in your main app.js file - [Gist](https://gist.github.com/tushargupta51/78ce0b6bce998f6851abd02d91eb3a95)

From my experience, the second approach doesn't work for anything but very basic apps. You will need to implement the first solution which takes an iFrame based approach.